# Receipt of Funds from Outside of India via International bank transfer - Purpose of Remittance

Tags: united-states, india, income, consulting

If I am receiving money from international bank in my Indian bank account for my work done . I have to give explanation about the remittance. What is the minimum amount of receiving fund from foreign bank?

Answer (score 1):

There is no minimum amount. Read the [RBI Circular](https://rbi.org.in/Scripts/ECMUserView.aspx?Id=24#a3a_2), if the amount is more that Rs 1,00,000; then purpose of remittance needs to be recorded. This l[ink gives out the various purpose of remittance](https://www.rbi.org.in/upload/notification/pdfs/52220.pdf). It is best advised to consult a professional CA for advise in your specific case.